# Does AWS RDS support having log files on a separate disk from the data?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We are seeing bad performance from the disk subsystem (high PAGEIOLATCH_SH) on our SQL Server 2016 SP3 hosted on AWS RDS.

The log files are on the same drive as the data files, which in my book is bad practice - is there a way to change this? I can't find anything in the AWS RDS UI that lets me configure this; but maybe I'm just blind (often am).

Comment: RDS does not give you control over the actual instance configuration. I have no experience with SQLServer, but a quick Google tells me that it's a wait incurred on reads, which probably wouldn't be improved by moving the logs (I'm assuming transaction logs) to another volume. What _would_ probably help is increasing the IO capacity available from your existing volume, either by increasing the size of the volume (if GP2) or using provisioned IOPS. Have you looked at the IO stats for the instance in CloudWatch?

Comment: @Parsifal we do also see high a high WRITELOG - but it is GP2 so I'll try with IOPS. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I recommend increasing the size of the volume first. Or switch to GP3, which I believe gives a baseline of 3,000 IOPS. Provisioned IOPS can get really expensive.